# Magento 2 Load specific attribute on front end

Tags: magento, attributes, magento2

I'm trying to modify the product page. I know what files I need to change, however I can't seem to work out what specific thing I need to do.

How do you load a specific attribute to display on the product page? I want a specific one to appear in a more prominent position than the "More Information" tab.

I can sort out the styling and layout stuff, I just need to know how to grab a specific attribute.

Additional question: I've set one up as "Image Swatch". Is there a way to get it to display the image on the front end (it only seems to images when it's a product option).

Answer (score 4):

**Best way -  Create a block**
You can edit the relevant XML file to create a block and position it where you need it. You can add a container (a div with a specific class) if you need to;

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

**In the phtml template**
If your working inside a phtml template you co do the below;

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('size');?>
```

**Reference**
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#xml-manage-block

If anyone has a better way it would be interesting to find out.

Comment: Why `$_product->getAttributeText('size')` ?

Comment: How should I write my arguements if the attribute is a dropdown box value? This block method works great for text input attributes, but it only displays a number on the frontend for dropdown attributes.

Comment: To show the dropdown option value instead of id you can add `<argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>` to the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can also load attribute in custom template by:

```
 <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); ?>
```

Comment: You should never code it like this, thats dirty. Always move such code into the block class